# Do we need RxSwift on Apple platforms (iOS, MacOS etc) now that we have Combine?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming

Pardon my naivete (I never used RxSwift): do we need RxSwift in **new** projects (with iOS deployment target 13+) on Apple platforms now that we have Combine?
Why?
Thanks.

Comment: yes, because Combine is not available on Linux or Win platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RXSwift supports iOS9 and above on the other hand combine is supports iOS13 and above.

If you are supporting iOS versions below 13 such as 11,12 combine is not be an option for you but RXSwift will help you there.

Also, a point to note would be combine works well with SwiftUI.

So the short answer is you don't need Rxswift if you are using combine but also depends on your use case.

Also SPatel mentioned that unterplatforms such as Windows don't have Combine so poor fellas that are perverted enough to use Swift on Win could have a use of RxSwift.